# Diifbot Product Api version 3 is returning images .But PRODUCT API CRAWL job doesn't . How can I get images in product api crawl job?

Tags: web-crawler, product, diffbot

Diifbot product api version 3 is returning images . But when I am creating product api crawl job, it doesn't return any image . How can I get images in product api crawl job ?

Comment: Could you give an example of the URLs you're using? Leave out the token, I'll test with my own.

Comment: Sorry for late answer Swader. I got my all answer from Diffbot support . Thank you.